# Android SDK Root folder not found

Tags: android, android-studio, appium, appium-android

I am using Appium to test applications on Mobile phones. However, I receive the following error when I try to start an inspector session on Appium:

`The Android SDK root folder does not exist on the local file system.`

I have added the following path to my system variables: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio with the name ANDROID_HOME

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from your Android Studio go to `File > Settings > System Settings > Android SDK > edit` then locate your Android SDK from your Hard drive. if you don't have downloaded that SDK then downloads it from this URL [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio) or uninstall Android Studio and install it freshly.